# ng-repeat is not working with Snap svg zpd

Tags: angularjs, snap.svg

I am trying to load multiple rectangles using ng-repeat in an SVG container which is enabled with Snap svg zpd. Rectangles are not getting rendered in UI. Plunker link is attached [Snapsvgzpd+angular js](https://plnkr.co/edit/rkFFZ7)

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html ng-app="plunker">

<head>
<meta charset="utf-8" />
<title>AngularJS svg with zoom and pan Plunker</title>
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/angular.js/1.5.3/angular.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/snap.svg/0.4.1/snap.svg-min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/snap.svg.zpd/0.0.11/snap.svg.zpd.js"></script>
<script src="app.js"></script>
 </head>
<body ng-controller="MainCtrl">
<div>
  <svg id="diagram" style="border: solid 1px #ccc; width: 400px; height:400px;" class="svg-drop" height="500px" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" version="1.1">
  <g id="group" >
    <image x="0" y="0" width="784" height="391" xlink:href="http://www.slashroot.in/sites/default/files/advanced%20static%20routing%20config.png"></image>
    <rect ng-repeat="ar in arr" ng-attr-x="{{ar.x + 30}}" ng-attr-y="{{ar.x + 150}}" width="25" height="25" fill="red"></rect>
    <rect x="0" y="0" width="25" height="25" fill="red"></rect>
  </g>
</svg>
</div>
```

```
var app = angular.module('plunker', []);

app.controller('MainCtrl', function($scope) {
$scope.arr = [{x:10},{x:20},{x:30}];
var paper = Snap("#diagram");
paper.zpd();

});
```

Console error:[image]

If I remove snap svg and snap svg zpd, rectangles are getting rendered.

[image]

Comment: Try posted answer.

Comment: @JigarPrajapati I tried it, issue remains same. Not able to load rectangles in ng-repeat.

Answer (score 0):

You need to just remove braces from ng-attr-x="{{ar.x + 30}}" ng-attr-y="{{ar.x + 150}}"

```js
var app = angular.module('plunker', []);

app.controller('MainCtrl', function($scope) {
  $scope.arr = [{x:10},{x:20},{x:30}];
  var paper = Snap("#diagram");
  paper.zpd();

});
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html ng-app="plunker">

  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <title>AngularJS svg with zoom and pan Plunker</title>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/angular.js/1.5.3/angular.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/snap.svg/0.4.1/snap.svg-min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/snap.svg.zpd/0.0.11/snap.svg.zpd.js"></script>
    <script src="app.js"></script>
  </head>
  <body ng-controller="MainCtrl">
    <div>
      <svg id="diagram" style="border: solid 1px #ccc; width: 400px; height:400px;" class="svg-drop" height="500px" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" version="1.1">
      <g id="group" >
        <image x="0" y="0" width="784" height="391" xlink:href="http://www.slashroot.in/sites/default/files/advanced%20static%20routing%20config.png"></image>
        <rect ng-repeat="ar in arr" ng-attr-x="ar.x + 30" ng-attr-y="ar.x + 150" width="25" height="25" fill="red"></rect>
        <rect x="0" y="0" width="25" height="25" fill="red"></rect>
      </g>
    </svg>
    </div>
    
  </body>

</html>
```

Comment: Result is the same

Comment: That is i think problem about to loading svg